# How to compile nested Directives in Jasmine for unit test?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am currently compiling a directive for unit test $compile('custom directive' )(scope); It does compile the directive, but the custom directives nested within the directive remain uncompiled. Is there a way to compile nested directives?

Comment: What leads you to believe the custom directive is not compiled ? Can you create plnkr modeling http://embed.plnkr.co/O1otV47VxsIL5krAdUW0/preview

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question for anyone who sees this. The reason they were not compiling was because I needed to reference the nested directives as a dependency within the parent directive. You do not need to do this in angular for it to work on the front-end. It doesn't work with Jasmine because it recognizes it as just a plain html element(this is expected and valid) unless you specify the dependency for it to recognize it as an angular directive. This is also the reason why Jasmine didn't throw a dependency error.